# What is the purpose of ForeachWriter in Spark Structured Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

Can someone explains what is the need of foreach writer on spark structured streaming ?

As we get all source data in the form of dataFrame, i am not getting the use of foreachwriter.

Answer (score 7):

A DataFrame is an abstract Spark concept, and does not directly map into a format that can be acted on, such as written to the console or a database.

By creating a `ForeachWriter`, you are taking the rows (or batches) of a DataFrame, and are defining how to `open()` a destination system you want to write to, how to `process()` that event, then finally `close()` the opened resources.

Using JDBC database as an example, you would establish a database session in `open()`, and perhaps define a `PreparedStatement` which maps to the data you want to add, you can then `process()` some generic type `T` to do whatever actions you want like bind some fields to the statement. And finally, when finished, you close the database connection.

In the case of writing to the console, there is nothing really to open or close, but you would need to `toString` each field of the DataFrame, then print it

---

The use cases, I feel, are well [laid out in the documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach-and-foreachbatch), and basically it is saying that for any system that doesn't offer you a `writeStream.format("x")` way of writing data, then you need to implement this class yourself to get data into your downstream systems.

Or, if you need to write to multiple destinations, you can cache the Dataframe before writing both locations such that the dataframe doesn't need recomputed, and result in inconsistent data between your destinations

Comment: Can ForeachWriter has multiple connection for write to multiple location? For example, write dataframe to JDBC and HBase in the same ForeachWriter. Because, Spark 2.3 doesn't supports cache dataframe, and I don't want recompute the dataframe.

Comment: Yes. multiple locations pattern per databricks docs is this:  ```streamingDF.writeStream.foreachBatch { (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>
  batchDF.persist()
  batchDF.write.format(...).save(...)  // location 1
  batchDF.write.format(...).save(...)  // location 2
  batchDF.unpersist()
}```
for more info, see: "Write to multiple locations" section of this article: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/structured-streaming/foreach.html

Comment: That's not using the same ForeachWriter

Comment: Where is this `forEachBatch` - it is not shown as any method off of `DataStream`.  Is it gone now - in favor of `forEach` ?  I actually prefer a `forEachBatch` ..

Comment: @javadba As that link says, it seems to only be available in Databricks Runtime

Comment: @Chris Bedford, your statement is not wrong, but isn't really correct for liveisshort's question. The foreachbatchwriter is not supported in spark 2.3, it only became available in Spark 2.4+.

Answer (score 0):

In spark structured streaming df.writeStream currently is not supported for lot of stores like Jdbc, Hbase etc this is the primary use case for ForeachWriter, ForeachWriter will allow you write logic for connection creation & saving, so that you can save streaming data to any data stores. Another use case is when you want add custom logic & not just save. For more details refer doc https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach-and-foreachbatch.

Incase if you are thinking about df.write(), Structured streaming dataframe data is continually updated so df.write option is ruled out as it is only for batch dataframes and not supported in streaming cases.