# Call a function with each element a stream in Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, databricks

I have a DataFrame stream in Databricks, and I want to perform an action on each element. On the net I found specific purpose methods, like writing it to the console or dumping into memory, but I want to add some business logic, and put some results into Redis.

To be more specific, this is how it would look like in non-stream case:

```
val someDataFrame = Seq(
  ("key1", "value1"),
  ("key2", "value2"),
  ("key3", "value3"),
  ("key4", "value4")
).toDF()

def someFunction(keyValuePair: (String, String)) = {
  println(keyValuePair)
}

someDataFrame.collect.foreach(r => someFunction((r(0).toString, r(1).toString)))
```

But if the `someDataFrame` is not a simple data frame but a stream data frame (indeed coming from Kafka), the error message is this:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;
```

Could anyone please help me solving this problem?

Some important notes:

- I've read the relevant documentation, like Spark Streaming or Databricks Streaming and a few other descriptions as well.
- I know that there must be something like `start()` and `awaitTermination`, but I don't know the exact syntax. The descriptions did not help.
- It would take pages to list all the possibilities I tried, so I rather not provide them.
- I do *not* want to solve the specific problem of displaying the result. I.e. please do not provide a solution to this specific case. The `someFunction` would look like this:

```
val someData = readSomeExternalData()
if (condition containing keyValuePair and someData) {
  doSomething(keyValuePair);
}
```

(Question [What is the purpose of ForeachWriter in Spark Structured Streaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53965025/what-is-the-purpose-of-foreachwriter-in-spark-structured-streaming) does not provide a working example, therefore does not answer my question.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of ForeachWriter in Spark Structured Streaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53965025/what-is-the-purpose-of-foreachwriter-in-spark-structured-streaming)

Comment: I don't find it duplicate, the referenced question does not provide an example which helps solving my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of reading using foreachBatch to save every item to redis using the streaming api.

Related to a previous question ([DataFrame to RDD[(String, String)] conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55335877/dataframe-to-rddstring-string-conversion/55347332#55347332))

```
// import spark and spark-redis
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

import com.redislabs.provider.redis._

// schema of csv files
val userSchema = new StructType()
    .add("name", "string")
    .add("age", "string")

// create a data stream reader from a dir with csv files
val csvDF = spark
  .readStream
  .format("csv")
  .option("sep", ";")
  .schema(userSchema)
  .load("./data") // directory where the CSV files are 

// redis
val redisConfig = new RedisConfig(new RedisEndpoint("localhost", 6379))
implicit val readWriteConfig: ReadWriteConfig = ReadWriteConfig.Default

csvDF.map(r => (r.getString(0), r.getString(0))) // converts the dataset to a Dataset[(String, String)]
  .writeStream // create a data stream writer
  .foreachBatch((df, _) => sc.toRedisKV(df.rdd)(redisConfig)) // save each batch to redis after converting it to a RDD
  .start // start processing
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this still does not work. It seems that Databricks has a different version of spark-redis and ReadWriteConfig  does not exist, so I just removed those lines. Indeed, at first I just try to do something very simple, printing the input. I created a test ; separated csv file, uploaded to data directory, changed the dir name to "dbfs:/data/", changed sc.toRedisKV(df.rdd)(redisConfig) to just println(df) and started the script. It is running but prints nothing. Should I extend my code with something like awaitTermination?

Comment: Directly applying just the csvDF.map part on my application (without ReadWriteConfig) it works; thank you!

Comment: I want to elaborate rows one by one because the logic is going to be more complex than just saving everything into Redis, but this fails with NotSerializableException. I posted another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55362469/azure-databricks-stream-foreach-fails-with-notserializableexception. Do you have an idea about this?

Comment: It must be another problem, a simple ForeachWriter[(String, String)] with DataSreamWriter would work

Answer (score 1):

Call simple user defined function foreachbatch in spark streaming.

please try this,
it will print 'hello world' for every message from tcp socket

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
from pyspark.sql.functions import split

spark = SparkSession .builder .appName("StructuredNetworkWordCount") .getOrCreate()
# Create DataFrame representing the stream of input lines from connection tolocalhost:9999
lines = spark .readStream .format("socket")  .option("host", "localhost") .option("port", 9999) .load()

# Split the lines into words
words = lines.select(
   explode(
       split(lines.value, " ")
   ).alias("word")
)


# Generate running word count
wordCounts = words.groupBy("word").count()
 # Start running the query that prints the running counts to the console
def process_row(df, epoch_id):
    # # Write row to storage
    print('hello world')

query = words.writeStream.foreachBatch(process_row).start()
#query = wordCounts .writeStream .outputMode("complete") .format("console") .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```